# Ways to purge data on restart, shutdown, and logoff

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, imaging, purge

What ways can do such thing as reverting(quickly) a pc's state back to an image on logoff, shutdown and restart.

Those pc's(runs windows 7) that I talked about are connected to a server. Students must have an account to log in. Once they logoff, shutdown, or restart. The pc reverts any changes made. It goes back to the image it was initially.

Question is do the colleges use a software to accomplish this or do they use a server to do so. I have no idea what it is as the operation is discreet and quick.

Please give a brief summary as how you think they do so.

I have some computers and a server to try with. But I am clueless as to what is used to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

We can't guess how "colleges" do this in general, but many use [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise/):

> Faronics Deep Freeze Enterprise makes PCs indestructible. It protects endpoints by Freezing the desired configuration set by the IT Admin. With a simple reboot, any unwelcome or unwanted changes are removed from the system, restoring it to the original state.

An alternative would be to setup a server and use a Virtual desktop Infrastructure ([VDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Virtual_desktop_infrastructure)) to give a fresh Virtual Desktop (from a base image) each time the log in.

Comment: VDI sounds like what they might used. When the internet is offline, users cannot log in to their accounts. And there is no need to restart the pc to rollback to its original image. A simple log off does the trick.

Comment: We use DeepFreeze. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring "Temporary User Profiles" for the student accounts would help in achieving this. This profile can revert changes made by the user to desktop settings and files are removed when the user logs off, restart or shutdown and it will revert to original position. For more details, refer this URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776892(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps...